# Joda DateTime hibernate mapping spring form

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, datetime, jodatime

I'm trying to map a DateTime object to a TimeStamp SQL column.

```
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;
...

    @Column
    @Type(type="org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime")
    @DateTimeFormat(style="SS")
    private DateTime dateSmoked;
```

I'm using Spring form  tag to get the user to enter a date input of the type "mm/dd/YYYY HR:MIN AM/PM" as according to @DateTimeFormat(style="SS"). I have imported joda-time-hibernate packages and all other necessary packages

When I submit the form I get the following error:
org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime.nullSafeSet(Ljava/sql/PreparedStatement;Ljava/lang/Object;ILorg/hibernate/engine/spi/SessionImplementor;)V

Its clear I'm doing something wrong. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you are using **Hibernate 4.+**.
`Joda-Time Hibernate` doesn't support this Hibernate version.
You can use usertype from `Jadira Framework`:
[**PersistentDateTime doc**](http://jadira.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/jadira/usertype/dateandtime/joda/PersistentDateTime.html)

```
    @Column
    @Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
    @DateTimeFormat(style="SS")
    private DateTime dateSmoked;
```

maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
    <artifactId>usertype.jodatime</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This works. You need Jadira Usertype and some other jadira librares.

Answer (score 1):

When using Hibernate's **`4.3.5.Final`** version (the last at the post creation time) I faced the same problem. As it was mentioned before, you have to use `Jadira Framework`

Java-code:

```
private DateTime creationDate;

@Column(name = "CREATION_DATE")
@Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
public DateTime getCreationDate() {
    return creationDate;
}
```

My `pom.xml` Hibernate-related section:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

My `pom.xml` JodaTime-related section:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
  <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
  <version>2.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
  <artifactId>usertype.jodatime</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

SQL script that created needed table (pay attention at **TIMESTAMP** type):

```
CREATE TABLE dropbox.MAPPING (ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, DROPBOX_URL VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL, SHORTENED_URL VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, CREATION_DATE TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, UNIQUE UQ_MAPPING (ID), PRIMARY KEY (ID));
```